# Xcode Simulator, cannot launch app in simulator on subsequent runs on Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I try to run my app on a simulator that already has the app installed, I received the following message:

This app could not be installed at this time.

> Could not install at this time.
> Could not hardlink copy /Users/matthewkrager/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FFB5EC3D-9AC7-432B-8634-BCAD78B56CC2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/948A502D-62E8-492F-89CF-871EEB35EA9B/Parfé.app to /Users/matthewkrager/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FFB5EC3D-9AC7-432B-8634-BCAD78B56CC2/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.HMFP20/extracted/Payload/Parfé.app with manifest /Users/matthewkrager/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FFB5EC3D-9AC7-432B-8634-BCAD78B56CC2/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.HMFP20/extracted/com.apple.deltainstallcommands.Krager.Foodprint

If I delete the app on the simulator and build and run, the app launches as normal, but from a fresh download. This is very annoying for testing as I can't rebuild!

Any ideas?
I have tried deleting all other version of xcode on machine and clearing derived data.
Also I suspect it may be because my app name has an é, but I'm not sure how to solve the problem
Thanks!

Comment: My project name is actually different that my "Display Name" my project (like the proj file) is "Foodprint.xcodeproj" and my Display name is "Parfé".

Comment: @matt above message is in response to you ^^